# Content-Length for dynamically resized image PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, image-processing, http-headers

I've written an PHP page to dynamically resize an image stored as a BLOB in a MySQL database. I'm doing this on the fly without storing any temporary files. Is there any way to determine a Content-Length to send in the header?

I have the image created with imagecopyresampled() and use imagepng() (or the like) to output the image data.

```
$origImage = imagecreatefromstring($image['data']);
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// preserve alpha
imagealphablending($newImage, false);
imagesavealpha($newImage, true);

$resizeSuccess = imagecopyresampled($newImage, $origImage, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $image['width'], $image['height']);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($newImage, null, $pngCompression, PNG_NO_FILTER);
imagedestroy($newImage);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of your `imagepng` call, try this:

```
ob_start(function($c) {
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($c));
    return $c;
});
imagepng($newImage, null, $pngCompression, PNG_NO_FILTER);
obj_end_flush();
```

Also, the server should handle `Content-Length` automatically for you.

Comment: Does your last comment here mean that I don't really need to send Content-Length because it's computed automatically by the imagepng() call? I've been reading that it's good to have a Content-Length so the browser knows the download progress.

Comment: It depends on how your server's set up, but it should really have the `Content-Length` sent already. As far as the server sees, it sees that it needs to serve an image (thanks to the `Content-Type` header), so it sends the relevant headers too.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'm not seeing on my local MAMP environment, but I'll check on production.